# How to insert characters such as "±, ≧, ≦" inside a table in PL/SQL

Tags: unicode, plsql

Here is the SQL I'm using to create my table:

```
create table LAB_REQUESTS_REQUREMENTS
(
  id                 INTEGER not null,
  request_id         INTEGER not null,
  test_id            INTEGER not null,
  requrement         VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  assistant_id       INTEGER,
  measured_result    VARCHAR2(50),
  measured_condition VARCHAR2(50),
  price_id           INTEGER not null,
  single_price       NUMBER(15,2) default 0 not null,
  measured_date      DATE,
  measure            NVARCHAR2(30),
  metric_tolerance   NVARCHAR2(30)
)
tablespace VIK
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

How should I go about inserting those characters inside 'MEASURE' for example without going through conversion when inserting and then reading from the table?

Comment: Show us your stored procedure

Comment: In `T-SQL` you can use a syntax like `N'Müller'`. Can you try this on `P-SQL`?